# Is there a way to query data assumed by inheritance?

Tags: elasticsearch, inheritance

If i have data that deals with inheritance and I want to query the inheritance, how can I do that with elasticsearch... example

```
all dealerships
  * ford cars
  * chevy cars
     |
     - Oregon Dealerships
       * no ford cars
       * mazda cars
         |
         - Portland dealership
         |   * ford cars
         |
         - Salem dealership
             * subaru cars

Show me all dealerships with ford/mazda/chevy
(Portland)

Show me all dealerships with chevy/Subaru
(Salem)


Show me all dealerships with ford
(all*)(portland)

* assume buckets can be returned as well as dealerships


Show me all dealerships
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in elasticsearch?

Comment: try nested type

Comment: try to provide ur mapping, sample docs, expected doc in json format

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this using nested mapping: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Once the index is created, data will populate in index w.r.t your mappings.

You can then further use nested queries:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html

Nested queries will help you achieve results you've mentioned in your question.

Comment: Im not sure I understand this well enough to implement a solution to my problem.